# FPDF initial index

Tags: pdf, indexing, fpdf

I am creating a pdf file, and I need to print an index on the second page, I know index in FPDF can only be generated at the end.

So when generated, I need to force it to be moved back to page 2.

(I'm using [bookmarks](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script1.php) and [index](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script13.php) scripts).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finnally found it, pretty simple.
Seems to be called "Table of contents", not index.

And it's posted on the script list at the official [FPDF page](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/index.php).

It's called "Table of contents" made by Richard Bondi.